# put part title instead of chapter's in headings

Tags: sectioning, parts

i would like to change my headings, instead of showing each time the current chapter title, i want to see the current Part title without "Part:"

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
\usepackage{verbatim}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\chapterstyle{tandh}
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\part{Hello}
\pagestyle{headings}
\chapter{yes}
\lipsum
\newpage
\lipsum
\chapter{no}
\lipsum
\chapter{maybe}
\end{document}
```

Thank you

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the pagestyle `headings` and then change the marks of the new page style:

```
\copypagestyle{partheadings}{headings}
\makepsmarks{partheadings}{%
  \createmark{part}{both}{nonumber}{}{}%
  \clearmark{chapter}%
  \clearmark{section}%
}
```

Now you can use

```
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{partheadings}
```

to set the page style inside the document.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
\usepackage{verbatim}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\chapterstyle{tandh}
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\copypagestyle{partheadings}{headings}
\makepsmarks{partheadings}{%
  \createmark{part}{both}{nonumber}{}{}%
  \clearmark{chapter}%
  \clearmark{section}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{partheadings}
\part{Hello}
\blinddocument

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{headings}% switch to normal headings
\part{Next}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a single `@`, nice :-)

Answer (score 1):

Modeling `\partmark` on `\chaptermark` and redefining the latter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} %paragraphes prédéfinis
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{}
\chapterstyle{tandh}
\renewcommand\partnumberlinebox[2]{#2\hspace{1em}}
\newcommand{\partmarksn}[1]{#1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{%
  \@setclcnt{part}{@memmarkcntra}%
  \advance\c@@memmarkcntra\m@ne
  \markright{%
    \memUChead{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\c@@memmarkcntra
        \if@mainmatter\@nameuse{partmarksn}{\partname. \ }\fi
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.5pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Hello}
\chapter{yes}
\lipsum
\newpage
\lipsum
\chapter{no}
\lipsum
\chapter{maybe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want “Première partie.”, then comment out three lines in the definition of `\partmark`:

```
\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{%
  \@setclcnt{part}{@memmarkcntra}%
  \advance\c@@memmarkcntra\m@ne
  \markright{%
    \memUChead{%
%      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\c@@memmarkcntra
%        \if@mainmatter\@nameuse{partmarksn}{\partname. \ }\fi
%      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Hamza.w Remove everything from `\ifnum` (included) to `#1` (excluded).

Comment: @Hamza.w I added how to do it

Comment: @Hamza.w You should remove `\pagestyle{headings}` as in my code.

Comment: i see, but i can't i mean  i have chapters in the middle of my document, before i have TOC and Introduction so i have to omit their headings ...
Can i use put \pagestye to the first pages and then change it to empty?

Comment: How to cancel the previous pagestyle @egreg ?

Comment: @Hamza.w Please, state your requirements in a clearer way.

Comment: i am writing a memoir, so i have many "includes" from the main .tex file and the first pages of my memoir are composed of "Preface, TOC..." which i don't want to have headings on them. So i use \pagestyle{empty} and when the body of my memoir starts 'the chapters as well', i have to use the command \pagestyle{headings} cause i used 'empty' style just before.